# Booting delay when auto-mounting Google Drive

Tags: mount, google-drive, ubuntu-18.04

I wanted to access my Google Drive via my terminal. To do this I installed `Google Drive Ocamlfuse` which seems to work fine.

At first I had to manually mount my Google Drive every time my computer restarted. To avoid doing this, I went into my `.profile` and added the line:

```
mountpoint ~/googledrive || google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/googledrive
```

This worked and my Google Drive was now mounted automatically on start up. The only thing that I have noticed is that when I boot up, between entering my login password and seeing the desktop, there is now a 15 (or so) second delay, which seems to be due to the mount on startup.

Is there anything I can do to improve this situation or is this just the price to pay if I want automatic mounting?

I am running Linux 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Try adding ` &` at the end of the line. Or do it with a systemd user service.

Comment: The & didn't seem to change anything. I will try systemd, thank you!